# How do I send email from a domain account when the domain was added using the NEW console on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Here's the situation: I have successfully set up email to come from a custom domain on App Engine before, but that was always done through the Google Apps for Business set up process. This time I have added the custom domain through the new developers console instead (https://console.developers.google.com/project/[APP_ID]/appengine/settings/domains) and  now I'm getting the "unauthorized sender" error every time.

I've tried a lot of variations on the set up process, checked for typos or other potential bugs repeatedly, and scoured both the docs and Stack Overflow without finding an answer. Most of the docs and answers that come up seem woefully out of date. The docs hardly ever reference the new developer console or the fact that Google Apps for Business doesn't have a free tier any more. And most of the answers seem to ignore the fact that the docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail) explicitly state that "Domain accounts do not need to be explicitly verified, since you will have verified the domain during the registration process."

So has anyone actually gotten domain accounts to work with the new process? Do I have to modify DNS records? DKIM? Something else I'm missing? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the account you are using to send email an appengine administrator or developer or isnt on the list?

Comment: No, they're not on the list or an admin or developer, because as the docs state and I mentioned above, that should be unnecessary because "Domain accounts do not need to be explicitly verified, since you will have verified the domain during the registration process."

Comment: Veridication of valid email has nothing to do with permission.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail):

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message **must be the
>   email address of an administrator** for the application or any valid
>   email receiving address for the app (see Receiving Mail). The sender
>   **can also be the Google Account email address of the current user** who
>   is signed in, if the user's account is a Gmail account or is on a
>   domain managed by Google Apps.

So only logged in Google accounts or admin (owners in the new console) addresses can be used to send emails through GAE. If you want to use a set of custom domain addresses you can either:

1) Add and validate all those addresses as owners in the project's "permissions" settings.

2) Use as external party to send your emails through a Web API, EG Sendgrid which gives you 25.000 emails/month for free for GAE developers (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid)

Comment: So what about the part of the docs that say, "Domain accounts do not need to be explicitly verified, since you will have verified the domain during the registration process." Is that just wrong?

Comment: From what I understand... It means you dont need to verify ownership over your domain or any domain for that matter , since you are not able to send emails on generic addresses on that domain you only need to verify that you are the "owner" of that single email address, which you do when you invite someone to become an owner on the console (registration?) . I'll admit the wording is a bit confusing.